# .not selector with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use multiple variables inside a `.not()` selector in jQuery?

e.g.

```
var target = $('.custom-element') // This must be in a variable
$('.element').not(this, target).toggleClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass multiple parameters to  [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/). However you can chain them

```
$('.element').not(target).not(this).toggleClass('visible');
```

You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to add the element `this` to existing group then it can used.

```
var target = $('.custom-element') ;
$('.element').not(target.add(this)).toggleClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this, for simplicity's sake. CSS rules allow for comma separated selectors:

```
var target = $('.custom-element') // This must be in a variable
$('.element, .custom-element').not(this).toggleClass('visible');
```